# IBM MobileFirst version 6.3.0 [project-upgrader] ERROR: FWLPL0019E

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When building a project with MFP CLI I opened a terminal window and navigated to the directory in an attempt to run the following commands:

```
mfp restart –d

mfp bd –d
```

After running the first command I received the following error (and could not proceed to the next command).

**upgrade:
[project-upgrader] ERROR: FWLPL0019E: Migrating the healthcare-mfpf project from
version 7.1.0.00.20160401-2103 to version 6.3.0.00.20160305-1806 has failed bec
ause migration to an older MobileFirst Studio is not supported.  Use MobileFirst
Studio of version 7.1.0.00.20160401-2103 or higher.

[project-upgrader] FINE: DEBUG_CROSS_RELEASE

[project-upgrader] ERROR: FWLPL0026E: Migrating the healthcare-mfpf project from
version 7.1.0.00.20160401-2103 to version 6.3.0.00.20160305-1806 has failed (FW
LPL0019E: Migrating the healthcare-mfpf project from version 7.1.0.00.20160401-2
103 to version 6.3.0.00.20160305-1806 has failed because migration to an older M
obileFirst Studio is not supported.  Use MobileFirst Studio of version 7.1.0.00.
20160401-2103 or higher.)**

I checked to see if MFP 7.1.0 was installed on my workstation. It seems that I have MFP 6.3.0 but there are 7.1.0 components. I have attached a couple of screenshots.

Best,

Christopher[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrJWE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start the question with CLI, but then start talking about Studio. Your flow is unclear.

Suggest that you will fix your dev environment first.

1. Backup your 6.3 project
2. Download Eclipse kepler or mars, start it with a *new* workspace
3. Install the 7.1 Studio plug-in from Eclipse marketplace

Try again.

If you actually do want to use CLI, then remove your studio installation (or make sure Eclipse is shut down). Make sure you have only CLI 7.1 installed.

Try again.